# Split column based on tabs or spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel, parsing

Column A has 3 columns worth of information. The data is human readable, but not machine readable, and I want to pivot the data. Is there a way to parse the data by spacing or tabs? In the formula bar, it appears that the data was tabbed.

[image: Image of Sheet]

Comment: It is probably using indentation, which is a format and not a physical character, and as such no, it will not be recognized.  To split the column one will need vba which can see the format of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data using Text to Columns and Fixed Widths for the columns. Drag the column breaks to the place where each successive indentation occurs.

Once you have done the T2C's, you will have some odd looking data. Looks like successive indents of 4 units, sothe first row would probably have cells A1:  Unit. B1:  ed S, C1:  tate, and D1:  s.

So now you put it back together in the obvious way. Start with the first open column, let's say column K, and `TEXTJOIN()` as appropriate. For instance, if cell A1 has anything in it, the join it and everything to its right with a formula in that first open column, so K1. If not and B1 has something in it, then join it and everything to its right in cell L1. And so on until all the columns the data was broken into are accounted for (A through J in this supposition).

Easy to set up the row in columns K through whatever. First one, K1 here, checks A1, acts accordingly. L1 checks K1 for anything other than "" and returns the appropriate joining, if any, if K1 was empty and returns "" if K1 had a result. And so on out the row to the point needed, all checking if a `TEXTJOIN()` of the preceding cells after K1 is "" or has a result and either does its own join or gives "" as appropriate.

Then copy that portion of the row down as needed. Once you have the results, copy and Paste|Special|Values back onto the original material.

Or copy the original to a new sheet (a helper sheet, not column, do all this, and copy, then Paste|Special|Values back onto the original sheet.

Once the formulas are set up, it's cookie cutter. Much easier than VBA. Unless you kill at VBA in which case, that's the gold standard, of course.